# Adding array in anonymous-class

Tags: java

In fact, I don't know how I can express. There is a code :

```
        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"},
                {"bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb"},

            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
```

I want to add new Object Array

```
{ "ccc" , "ccc", "ccc" , "ccc"}
```

Object [][] **at another class**. How can I add this array? In external class, How can I access there?

Comment: Make a public method that returns it.

Comment: I think, you should read about `TableModel`, how to set up a table model and access rows, fields and so on. Find help around here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: That isn't an anonymous class.

Comment: @SLaks Sorry. I didn't know that. how can I name method? `public void set new ...? ` What should I do?

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Java.   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: @bobbel Thank you. I will read that after dinner. I'm beginner of programming. It's so difficult T.T furthermore, english is more difficult for me. anyway, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call in your another class.

```
DefaultTableModel model  = (DefaultTableModel)myTable.getModel();
model.addRow({ "ccc" , "ccc", "ccc" , "ccc"} );
```

Read : [DefaultTableModel#addRow(..)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29)

Comment: The method addRow(Vector) in the type DefaultTableModel is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String)....... Do you know what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
Object[][] data {
                   {"aaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa"},
                   {"bbb", "bbb", "bbb", "bbb"}
                };


String[] columnNames {"Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4" };

DefaultTableModel model  = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

JTable table = new JTable(model);


Object[] row = { "ccc" , "ccc", "ccc" , "ccc"};
model.add(row);
```